# Error: 'Parameter self unfilled' on calling a class method in Pycharm when running a Kivy app

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

I keep getting this error every time I try to create a class. It doesn't matter if its in an external file and imported or it is in the same file.

The error I get is an unfilled self parameter but when I fill it, its underscored in red indicating an error. I've had this error when creating multiple programs and just resorted to creating functions and no classes because of it. This is seriously annoying and hindering my progress in learning. In this case the unfilled self parameter error comes on the line "MyApp.run()". Now this code below has came directly from the official Kivy documentation. Thanks in advance for any support.

```
    import kivy
    kivy.require("1.11.1")

    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    #from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

    class MyApp(App):

        def build(self):
            return Label(text="Hello World!")

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        MyApp.run()
```

The error I receive

```
    [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\jhowd\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-05-13_45.txt
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\jhowd\PycharmProjects\hungarian_tutor\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\jhowd\PycharmProjects\hungarian_tutor\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
    [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
    [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
    [CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
    sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
      File "C:\Users\jhowd\PycharmProjects\hungarian_tutor\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
        fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
      File "C:\Users\jhowd\PycharmProjects\hungarian_tutor\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_sdl2.py", line 13, in <module>
        from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,

    pil - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
      File "C:\Users\jhowd\PycharmProjects\hungarian_tutor\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
        fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
      File "C:\Users\jhowd\PycharmProjects\hungarian_tutor\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py", line 7, in <module>
        from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

    [CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hi! Plese provide an error message to us, we have to take a look on it to make guesses what's going on :)

Comment: Maybe it means pycharm files are corrupted somewhere. If this error does not make any sense to you, try to reinstall IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are not instantiating your MyApp class properly.

Try changing:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp.run()
```

to

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run() # Note the parentheses after MyApp
```

Additionally, make sure that you have all required dependencies installed. When I installed Kivy, I followed their installation literature [here](https://kivy.org/#download). I followed the installation instructions for Windows, but you will need to follow the instructions matching your OS. Once I did that and made the change noted above it ran successfully.